# Citing Praat script APA

Tags: phonetics, praat

I'm currently using a Praat script I found online and I would like to cite it in my thesis.
Does anyone know whether there is a specific APA format for citing Praat scripts? 
I've tried looking into other researchers' papers, but they seem to write their scripts themselves and just not cite them, I guess.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You mean a pre-existing script someone else wrote, or one that you wrote?

Comment: a script someone else wrote

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a lot of advice I gave in [this Academia Stack Exchange answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149630/cite-a-r-function-implementation-from-a-website/149669#149669) useful, though it relates to R scripts and LaTeX. Unless the script is available from a very stable repository, only citing the praat script may not be helpful in a few years time. It's better to ask the original author if you can republish it as an appendix, or make all your analysis scripts available in a stable repository.

Caveats out of the way, the APA citation style indicates how to cite software. [The APA style blog gives advice](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/01/how-to-cite-software-in-apa-style.html) on how to do so, and following that I would recommend a citation like:

> Smith, J. (2014). Name of Script or Function [Praat script]. Retrieved from https://www.example.com/praatScripts

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful :)